# Weird behavior with Java objects: supposedly the same process, different result

Tags: java, arrays, object, vector

I am experiencing a weird behavior with Java objects. I have this ComponentPlane.class with two different versions. Difference is marked by `******`.

First WORKING Version

```
package app.pathsom.som.output;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import app.pathsom.som.map.Lattice;
import app.pathsom.som.map.Node;

public class ComponentPlane extends JPanel{

private Lattice lattice;
private int componentNumber;
private double minValue;
private double maxValue;
private double origMinValue;
private double origMaxValue;

public ComponentPlane(Lattice lattice, int componentNumber){
    this.lattice = new Lattice();
    this.componentNumber = componentNumber;
    initLattice(lattice);
    initComponentPlane();
}

private void initLattice(Lattice lattice){
    this.lattice.setLatticeHeight(lattice.getLatticeHeight());
    this.lattice.setLatticeWidth(lattice.getLatticeWidth());
    this.lattice.setNumberOfNodeElements(lattice.getNumberOfNodeElements());
    this.lattice.initializeValues();
    this.lattice.setNodeHeight(lattice.getNodeHeight());
    this.lattice.setNodeWidth(lattice.getNodeWidth());

    this.lattice.setTotalNumberOfNodes(lattice.getTotalNumberOfNodes());

    for(int i = 0; i < lattice.getTotalNumberOfNodes(); i++){
        ******this.lattice.getLatticeNode()[i] = new Node(lattice.getLatticeNode()[i]);******
    }

}
}
```

The only difference of the second NON-WORKING version is with this FUNCTION REPLACING the FUNCTION above

```
private void initLattice(Lattice lattice){
    //same code here 

    for(int i = 0; i < lattice.getTotalNumberOfNodes(); i++){
        ******this.lattice.getLatticeNode()[i] = lattice.getLatticeNode()[i];******
    }

}
```

I have also tried doing a third non-working version which is...

```
private void initLattice(Lattice lattice){
    //same code here
    ******this.lattice.setLatticeNode(lattice.getLatticeNode());******
}
```

A constructor in the Node.class (WHICH is USED in the first WORKING version is this one...

```
public Node (Node node){
    this.xPos = node.xPos;
    this.yPos = node.yPos;
    this.numOfElements = node.numOfElements;
    this.cluster = -1;
    this.nodeIndex = node.getNodeIndex();
    for(int i = 0; i < this.numOfElements; i++){
        this.addElement(node.getDoubleElementAt(i));
    }
}
```

Lattice.class

```
public class Lattice {
private int latticeWidth;
private int latticeHeight;

private int numOfNodeElements;

private int nodeWidth;
private int nodeHeight;
private int totalNumOfNodes;

private Node[] latticeNodes;

private final int MAP_RADIUS = 225;

public Lattice(int latticeWidth, int latticeHeight, int numOfNodeElements){
    this.latticeWidth = latticeWidth;
    this.latticeHeight = latticeHeight;
    this.numOfNodeElements = numOfNodeElements;

    initializeLattice();
}

public Lattice(){
    this(10, 10, 3);
}

public void initializeValues(){
    totalNumOfNodes = this.latticeHeight * this.latticeWidth;
    latticeNodes = new Node[totalNumOfNodes];   //specify the array of nodes

    nodeWidth = (int) Math.floor(450/this.latticeWidth);
    nodeHeight = (int) Math.floor(450/this.latticeHeight);
}

protected void initializeLattice(){
    totalNumOfNodes = this.latticeHeight * this.latticeWidth;
    latticeNodes = new Node[totalNumOfNodes];

    nodeWidth = (int) Math.floor(450/this.latticeWidth);
    nodeHeight = (int) Math.floor(450/this.latticeHeight);

    //initialize colors

    for(int i = 0; i <totalNumOfNodes; i++){
        latticeNodes[i] = new Node(((i % this.latticeWidth) * nodeWidth) + nodeWidth / 2, 
                ((i / this.latticeWidth) * nodeHeight ) + nodeHeight/2, numOfNodeElements, i);
        latticeNodes[i].setNodeColor(new Color((int)(latticeNodes[i].getDoubleElementAt(0) 
                * 255), (int)(latticeNodes[i].getDoubleElementAt(1) * 255), (int) (latticeNodes[i].getDoubleElementAt(2) * 255)));
    }   
}

public int getLatticeHeight(){
    return latticeHeight;
}

public void setLatticeHeight(int latticeHeight){
    this.latticeHeight = latticeHeight;
}

public Node[] getLatticeNode(){
    return latticeNodes;
}

public void setLatticeNode(Node[] latticeNodes){
    this.latticeNodes = latticeNodes;
}

public int getLatticeWidth(){
    return latticeWidth;
}

public void setLatticeWidth(int latticeWidth){
    this.latticeWidth = latticeWidth;
}

public int getNodeHeight(){
    return nodeHeight;
}

public int getNodeWidth(){
    return nodeWidth;
}

public void setNodeHeight(int nodeHeight){
    this.nodeHeight = nodeHeight;
}

public void setNodeWidth(int nodeWidth){
    this.nodeWidth = nodeWidth;
}

public int getNumberOfNodeElements(){
    return numOfNodeElements;
}

public void setNumberOfNodeElements(int numOfNodeElements){
    this.numOfNodeElements = numOfNodeElements;
}

public int getTotalNumberOfNodes(){
    return totalNumOfNodes;
}

public void setTotalNumberOfNodes(int totalNumberOfNodes){
    this.totalNumOfNodes = totalNumberOfNodes;
}
}
```

A certain Visualization.class initiates all these actions and stores the ComponentPlane arrays. Here is the function

```
public void initComponentPlanes(){
    componentPlanes = new ComponentPlane[somtrainer.getLattice().getNumberOfNodeElements()];
    int size = somtrainer.getLattice().getNumberOfNodeElements();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.println(i + ": " + inputData.getVariableLabels()[i] + " size : " + size);
        componentPlanes[i] = new ComponentPlane(somtrainer.getLattice(), i);
        componentPlanes[i].setBounds((240 - 225)/2, (280-240)/2, 225, 240);
        componentPlanes[i].setOrigMaxMin(maxMin[i][0], maxMin[i][1]);
    }
}
```

My problems are

- The First one works fine. It creates HEATMAPS or COMPONENTPLANES for each component number (meaning they differ from each other) but I cannot use it as the line with ****** which references to the ("this.addElement....") in the Node.class constructor gives me OUTOFMEMORY error so it LAGS and FREEZES whenever I have many COMPONENTPLANES to do. (I am actually doing an ARRAY of COMPONENTPlane objects) so I decided to try the second and third option. I have already increased my heap size SO this is OUT of the question
- If I use the second and third one, I end up with no LAGS even with large amount of ComponentPlanes (probably less memory taking up because of creating new Node objects or idk) but these creates wrong heatmaps. All heatmaps are the same. And the thing is, all heatmaps are like the last element of the ComponentPlanes array (e.g. if I have ten ComponentPlane objects, all heatmaps look exactly like the tenth Component Object)

All of the heatmaps are like this - the same as the last heatmap in the array:

[image]

Is there a way to make the second and third one work?

Comment: TL,DR you need to post the minimal possible amount of code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Sorry pal, few people will be willing to read through all of your input ...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ sorry. I have a trouble explaining things so I always try explaining it longer. it's my habit. sorry for that

Comment: @GhostCat I have tried editting the question now. Thank you. I apologize. Could you help me now?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I have tried editting the question now. Thank you. I apologize. Could you help me now?

Comment: The main thing missing: your **Lattice** class. It looks like you got an **array** in there, and one method inits array elements, the other does not.

Comment: @GhostCat whenever I use the first one, it gives a correct result but not the second and third codes so I might be thinking it is not there. Ill put the Lattice class and the array of ComponentPlanes in a moment.

Comment: @GhostCat Another weird thing is, whenever I try using the second or third code: If I try to compare the values of each node elements using "equals.()" it returns true (Xposition, YPosition, indexNumber, even the values of the Node is the same). When I try printing the nodeColors, it is different from the painted one. The painted Color is all the same - the last element of the ComponentPlane array. 
For example
Component 1 Node 1 has RGB(255, 0, 0)
while the last Component 10 Node 1 has RGB(0, 0, 255), 
the program does print RGB(255, 0, 0) but paints RGB(0, 0, 255)

Comment: @GhostCat quick question sir, is there a big difference on the line of code on 1 and 2 marked with *****?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious difference is that in the first one you're creating new nodes, and in the others you're reusing the old ones.  The line

```
this.lattice.getLatticeNode()[i] = lattice.getLatticeNode()[i];
```

is setting one object equal to another.  If, later, a property of `lattice.getLatticeNode()[i]` changes, that will also effect `this.lattice.getLatticeNode()[i]`.  And that can cause hard-to-find bugs.  In contrast, the line

```
this.lattice.getLatticeNode()[i] = new Node(lattice.getLatticeNode()[i]);
```

is creating a new object, distinct from the old one.  But, of course, this means that you're using more memory, because now you have two objects instead of one.

There are little things you can do to reduce the amount of memory used.  `private final int MAP_RADIUS = 225;` could be made static, so a new copy of the constant isn't created for each node.

Comment: thank you for the response. is there a way to mimic this.lattice.getLatticeNode()[i] = new Node(lattice.getLatticeNode()[i]); by using this.lattice.getLatticeNode()[i] = lattice.getLatticeNode()[i]; or by not making another node? Im getting the outofmemory error because of this actually. I might be creating too many nodes.

Comment: It starts lagging whenever I have 700+ weights/elements per node and 289 nodes. So it is 700 x 289 = 202390 nodes created on ComponentPlane array size 289. Do you have any advice on how to efficiently do it if YOU would SUGGEST me to just use the one instantiating new Node()? Basically, I am creating an array of heatmaps. Then after creating them, I go again in the loop of all ComponentPlanes then put them in a JPanel.

Comment: If you aren't creating new Nodes, the nodes are going to be tied together and all your heatmaps are going to be the same - if you want them to be separate, they HAVE to be separate objects.  I'd work on making the `Node` class as compact as possible.  If you have a class-level `double` variable in `Node`, see if you can make it a `float` instead.  If you have an `int`, see if it can be a `short` or even a `byte`.  You may have to do some casting, but it's probably worth it since memory is an issue for you.